# Using conda along with tmux

Tags: conda, tmux

I have added a conda environment to my bash_profile so that it loads on startup. However I find that if I use tmux to start a new session, the terminal behaves like the conda environment was never activated. How do i fix it? I am ok with solution on adding tmux to the `bash_profile`

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366553/tmux-is-causing-anaconda-to-use-a-different-python-source

Answer (score -1):

You can either add it to `bash_profile` like you noted or run `tmux setenv X $X` from the `tmux` session you need to have your variable.